# Aligning all the tabPanels in one line R Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am trying to align `tabPanels` in `tabBox`  on the same line, even if window size is changed. 
Is there any way to do it?

Please advice.

**Rshiny Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(

    tabBox(
      height = "250px",
      selected = "Tab3",
      tabPanel("Tabasdasd1", "Tab content 1"),
      tabPanel("Tabadad2", "Tab content 2"),
      tabPanel("Tabasdasd3", "Tab content 3"),
      tabPanel("Tabasdas4", "Tab content 4"),
      tabPanel("Tabasdas5", "Tab content 5"),
      tabPanel("Tabadasd6", "Tab content 6"),
      tabPanel("Tabasdas7", "Tab content 7"),
      tabPanel("Tabasdafsds7", "Tab content 8"),
      tabPanel("Tabasdassa", "Tab content 9")

    )
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"), dashboardSidebar(), body),
  server = function(input, output) {
    # The currently selected tab from the first box

  }
)
```

Comment: maximing the `width` argument of `tabBox` should help (e.g., width = 12), thouh if you resize the browser window sooner or later the tabs will be split in more lines.

Comment: I know that increasing width will help. I am looking for a solution where resizing should not affect alignment

Comment: Then I guess you're out of luck... I do not think that you can turn off the responsive resizing. Even the `responsive` argument to `fixedRow`/`fluidRow` is apparently not working anymore on bootstrap 3 (https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-stop-responsiveness-in-shiny-apps/5482/2).

Comment: Is a scrollbar allowed?

Comment: @EliBerkow I suppose, scrollbar should work. Any idea how to control tabBox scrolling?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With scrollbar:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

body <- dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(

        tabBox(
            height = "250px",
            selected = "Tabasdasd3",
            tabPanel("Tabasdasd1", "Tab content 1"),
            tabPanel("Tabadad2", "Tab content 2"),
            tabPanel("Tabasdasd3", "Tab content 3"),
            tabPanel("Tabasdas4", "Tab content 4"),
            tabPanel("Tabasdas5", "Tab content 5"),
            tabPanel("Tabadasd6", "Tab content 6"),
            tabPanel("Tabasdas7", "Tab content 7"),
            tabPanel("Tabasdafsds7", "Tab content 8"),
            tabPanel("Tabasdassa", "Tab content 9")

        ),
        tags$head(
            tags$style(
                'ul.nav.nav-tabs {
                    overflow-y: hidden;
                    display: flex;
                }'
            )
        )
    )
)

shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"), dashboardSidebar(), body),
    server = function(input, output) {
        # The currently selected tab from the first box

    }
)
```

Tested with Chrome DevTools to view on different devices and it looks good on a mobile:

[image: mobile]

and on a normal pc:

[image: pc]